# Is there a way to log into my PS4 account on a work PS4 without giving my colleagues credit card access?

Tags: ps4

Step 1: Log into PS4 on my work machine

Step 2: Check the PS store

Step 3: See that this has given my colleagues access to my personal credit card

Step 4: Attempt to secure that user so the account can stay on the machine without everyone having access

Step 4a: Fail at step 4

Step 5: REMOVE THE ACCOUNT RIGHT NOW

---

I would like to be able to log my home account in as a user on the work machine without granting access to my credit card to all users.

Is there a way to password protect my user account?

Comment: @Corsaka Please don't post answers in comments.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Would that have classified as an answer? I'm basing this off what Egor Skriptunoff does in SO's `lua` tag.

Comment: @Corsaka It's offering a solution to the problem so yes, it's an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a 4-digit passcode for your profile. Just go to Settings -> Users -> Login Settings -> Passcode Management and set up a passcode. You'll have to make sure you sign out after your session is done, too.

Comment: Will that affect all boxes, or just my work box?

Comment: It's a local passcode, so just your work ps4 (as long as that's what you set it up on)

Answer (score 0):

You should already be requiring password before making purchases. You can also require password to sign into your user account. The smarter thing would be to not use a work PS4 to browse the PS Store. Do that at home.

Comment: It's more that the MasterCard appears to be available at the account level, not the box level. So even if I don't browse the store, I need to prevent someone "browsing it for me"

Comment: If they can't make purchases, what's the issue? Are you worried they'll sit there trying to guess your password? I guess the other easiest solution is to just use a guest/secondary account for work..

Comment: Need to double check if the house account actually doesn't require a password before a purchase, but it's obviously harder to confirm that's working without actually buying something. The passcode on the user is a great solution for my issue.